# Celery-RabbitMQ Distributed Queue Test Message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I keep getting:`ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://ec2celeryuser` when I run `celery -A tasks worker` on terminal.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get celery/rabbitmq working properly across (2) ec2 instances. To pass a silly task in `tasks.py` for processing to rabbitmq.

1. Instance 1 - Houses rabbitMQ

This currently runs RabbitMQ fine. If I run `sudo rabbitmqctl status` it outputs:

```
Status of node 'rabbit@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx' ...
[{pid,786},
```

2. Instance 2 - Houses Celery

I'm trying to run celery on `instance 2` against Instance 1 using the following in terminal:

celery -A tasks worker

I have a file `celeryconfig.py`:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://ec2celeryuser:mypasshere@xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672/celeryserver1/'

#CELERY SETTINGS
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks",)

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

I have a file `client.py`:

```
from tasks import add

result = add.delay(4, 4) # call task
result_sum = result.get(timeout=5) # wait to get result for a maximum of 5 seconds
```

I have a file `tasks.py`:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://ec2celeryuser:mypasshere@xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672/celeryserver1/')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I've properly setup a `vhost`, a user `ec2celeryuser`, and gave this user permissions of:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /celeryserver1 ec2celeryuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

if I do: `sudo rabbitmqctl list_users` on RabbitMQ (instance 1) it shows:

```
ec2celeryuser   []
guest   [administrator
```

I've tried both usernames with their passwords, but no change.

I've been following the [Celery Guide](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html), and a [tutorial](http://www.sammyliu.com/2011/06/23/celery-simple-distributed-tasks-with-celery-and-rabbitmq) without much luck.

What am I doing wrong here? Clearly there is a connection issue, but what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: a wild guess, but do you have some weird character in your password?

Comment: Nope, its alphanumeric, no special char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user `natdempk` for helping me fix the configuration syntax of a queues.

The issue was creating a `vhost` in rabbitmq like:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost /celeryserver1
```

when it should have been:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost celeryserver1
```

I then had to reset the permissions for my user `ec2celeryuser` like:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p celeryserver1 ec2celeryuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

The way I realized this was the issue was: I visited `/var/log/rabbitmq/<last log file.log>`

and saw:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Apr-2014::12:45:58 ===
accepted TCP connection on [::]:5672 from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45964

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Apr-2014::12:45:58 ===
starting TCP connection <x.xxx.x> from from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45964

=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Apr-2014::12:46:01 ===
exception on TCP connection <x.xxx.x> from from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45964
{channel0_error,opening,
                {amqp_error,access_refused,
                            "access to vhost 'celeryserver1/' refused for user 'ec2celeryuser'",
                            'connection.open'}}
```

Since fixing the vhost, I now pleasantly see:

```
[2014-04-30 13:08:10,101: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx ready.
```

Answer (score 1):

So I see a few things wrong here. First your broker URL for rabbitMQ in `tasks.py` doesn't seem correct. It should read something like below.

`app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://ec2celeryuser:ec2celerypassword@xx.xxx.xx.xx/celeryserver1/')`

Also you might want to specify the app you want celery to serve when you run the worker process. You can do this by running `celery -A tasks worker` from the directory `tasks.py` is located in.

Another thing is your code in `client.py` to call your task seems incorrect. From the celery documentation, you can call the task as follows:

```
from tasks import add

result = add.delay(4, 4) # call task
result_sum = result.get(timeout=5) # wait to get result for a maximum of 5 seconds
```

Fixing these might solve your issue, or at least get you closer.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I've implmented this, but still getting the ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://ec2celeryuser@xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672/celeryserver1/  any other thoughts?

Comment: @CodeTalk I think your broker URL's are still wrong. They should be of the form: `amqp://user:password@IP:port/vhost/`

Comment: @CodeTalk are you still missing :port in `broker`?

Comment: Its there. All code is up to date. Any ideas? Still throwing same issue

Comment: I did this: sudo rabbitmqctl list_users  and it shows: ec2celeryuser []    guest [administrator]   could this be problematic?

Comment: Additionally, I tried using guest:guest in the connections and that didn't matter. Thoughts??

Comment: I fixed it. Posting solution. Thanks for your help with trying to get the configuration up to par

Comment: @CodeTalk glad to see you got it fixed.